# Were multiple notifications re-enabled (and then disabled again) in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

I noticed it just now with the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184068/decimal-tostring-formatting-which-gives-at-least-1-digit-no-upper-limit/8184130#8184130) (fourth comment down, addressed to @Stian and @AnthonyPegram on `2011-11-18 14:51`) and I verified in my comment responses that I could indeed mention multiple people in the comments.

But according to the [second point in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) ("[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)"):

> You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter or editor, by using
>   @name, where name is the username with all spaces removed.

There used to be a dialog that informed us that we couldn't do this, which leads to the following questions:

- Are multiple notifications allowed again?  If not, then
- Was the error dialog removed?  If so, then
- Doesn't this give the user a false impression that their notification will be delivered?

Additionally, the rule is still enforced in meta:

[image: Single comment notification warning]

It seems that the behavior is enforced again.

So what happened, was it a blip in the system?

Comment: Here's a comment for you to test this.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: The commenting *here* is not the issue, it was the commenting on SO that is the issue.  Testing it here doesn't prove anything.  Updated title and question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing has changed there. Shortly after this popup was introduced, there was a complaint here on Meta (I can't find it right now) where somebody tried to post code that contained several "@" characters (or something like that) in a comment, which failed with this popup being the reason.

Since that's a valid issue, and the "only one additional @user" popup is mainly a nice-to-have, what was done was the simplest thing someone could come up with: Just don't show the popup if the comment text contains a backtick. (Additionally, when someone knows how to format code in comments, chances are pretty good that they know about other comment rules as well.)

> and I verified in my comment responses that I could indeed mention multiple people in the comments.

I have no idea what you verified and how, but rest assured that the "only one additional user" thing is still in place.

Comment: See the link to the question which I commented on (the link and the position of the comment, as well as the date are in the first line of the question).  It mentions the specific comment.  I was able to get two notifications in.  That's the verification.

Comment: Read my answer. You were able to get the comment through, because the comment contains backticks. That doesn't mean Anthony was notified of your comment.

Comment: I see it now.  An odd quirk, to say the least.